# What Android-Application Components can bind to a Service?

Tags: android, components, bind, bindable

I just got the Exception

> BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services.

I found nothing about this online, so I am asking if anyone can provide a List of Components that are actually able to bind to a service, because I currently only know about `Activities`.

*Like, can Services bind to each other?*

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle, this is the only exception, so yes, services can bind to other services

Answer (score 0):

Components which can bind a service:

> **`Application`**, **`Activity`**, **`Service`**, **`ContentProvider`**

Component which can not bind a service:

> **`BroascastReceiver`**